# What is the origin of the term "Crystal Ball Condition"?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, terminology, uniform-integrability

Given $p>0$ and a family of random variables $\{X_{n}\}$,  the uniform integrability of $\{|X_{n}|^{p}\}$ follows from the existence of a $\delta>0$ such that 
$$
\sup_{n} E(|X_{n}|^{p+\delta})<\infty.
$$
This is called the "Crystal Ball Condition" (see for example Resnick, A Probability Path, Section 6.5.1).  What is the origin of the term?

Comment: My guess is that it is related to the fact that all the $X_n$ are contained in a ball of the $L^{p+\delta}$ norm.  But that is purely a guess.

Comment: Maybe it comes from the Crystal Ball collaboration, a hermetic particle detector at Stanford. The lab came up with the Crystal Ball function, which is a probability density function.